# Python change format for only certain items in list

Tags: python, mysql, null, nonetype

I have a list like this:

```
lst = ['3:44:44', '1.', '0', '2P', 'ri', 'NULL', 'fs']
```

And I used this code to get it into this format (because I'm going to insert it into a mysql table):

```
"'{}'".format("','".join(lst))
```

Output:

```
'3:44:44','1.','0','2P','ri','NULL','fs'
```

Which is almost exactly what I want, except I do not want the NULL in quotes (if it goes in as quotes then mysql interprets that as 0, but I need it to be inserted as null). I also have many lists that I need to make sure the NULL is not in quotes but everything else is. How can I do this?

I also tried using python's None instead of 'NULL' but when I need to change the format from a list to comma separated values, python doesn't like the NoneType.

Comment: you could search/replace the quoted NULL...

Comment: Does NULL need to be in that exact position in the string ?

Comment: @lee-pai-long Yes, it does. The order matters for everything I'm inserting.

Comment: `"'{}'".format("','".join(lst)).replace("'NULL'", 'NULL')`

Comment: You can try get this value ? `'3:44:44','1.','0','2P','ri',NULL,'fs'`

Comment: Can you switch the list to a dict ?

Comment: Thank you, the search and replace method worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this also work:

```
>>> lst = ['3:44:44', '1.', '0', '2P', 'ri', 'NULL', 'fs']
>>> print ("'{}'".format("','".join(lst)).replace("'NULL'", 'NULL'))
'3:44:44','1.','0','2P','ri',NULL,'fs'
```

Comment: nice solution ;)

Comment: We both think the same solution @sKwa

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting it as a string why not ignore the "Null". So the input goes in like

```
lst = ['3:44:44', '1.', '0', '2P', 'ri', 'NULL', 'fs'].

"'{}'".format("','".join([x if x!='NULL' else '' for x in lst]))
```

Output should be then

> "'3:44:44','1.','0','2P','ri','','fs'"

It should read the '' as empty value or null.

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic clear way:

```
In [41]: def quote_item(item):
    ...:     if item == "NULL":
    ...:         return item
    ...:     else:
    ...:         return "'{}'".format(item)
    ...:   

In [42]: result = ",".join(quote_item(item) for item in lst)

In [43]: print(result)
'3:44:44','1.','0','2P','ri',NULL,'fs'
```